# Existing array formula, need to add date restriction

Tags: excel

I have been tailoring an excel sheet for budget analysis using a pivot table.
Works quite well actually! 
One of the fields I have above the table is a reporting of the 1st, 2nd and (depending on the schedule the 3rd) pay check in a month.
Right now I am using this formula:

1st

```
=INDEX(bk_download!$D$2:$D$200, SMALL(IF(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx", ROW(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200)-ROW(INDEX(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200,1,1))+1),1))
```

2nd

```
=INDEX(bk_download!$D$2:$D$200, SMALL(IF(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx", ROW(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200)-ROW(INDEX(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200,1,1))+1),2))
```

3rd

```
=INDEX(bk_download!$D$2:$D$200, SMALL(IF(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx", ROW(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200)-ROW(INDEX(bk_download!$B$2:$B$200,1,1))+1),3))
```

As you can see in the formula, it's referencing another sheet in the file.  What I am trying to do is move the source data to a whole separate file that will be a continuous dump of our bank statements.  I've successfully pointed the pivot table source to the new file and it's pulling everything in fine, then applying a date filter for the table for whichever month we're on (set manually).
The catch with this formula I pasted is it works great for finding the 1st, 2nd and 3rd occurrence of the specified keywords, but of course only if a months worth of data is in the sheet.
How would this be changed to allow a date filter?
I.e cells A1 and B2 would be 5/1/18 and 5/31/18, use those two cells to define what the formula should look within to return the needed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** New formula. `AND` doesn't behave that way with array formulas.

Just add the date conditions to your `IF` statement. Say your dates in `bk_download` were in column `A` and your filter dates were in `A1` and `B1`, this should work for the first formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$32, SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$32="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx")+($A$2:$A$32<=$B$1)+($A$2:$A$32>=$A$1)=3, ROW($B$2:$B$32)-ROW(INDEX($B$2:$B$32,1,1))+1),1)),"None")
```

Change "None" to whatever value/message you want when nothing is found.

Comment: Thanks for the option.
The date cell refs would be on the current sheet and the actual data to be indexed would be in the Transactions.xlsx sheet.
I tried to edit the formula to what is below, but it's not coming up with any result.
What sticks out as not being correct?

Comment: =INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$D$2:$D$9000, SMALL(IF(AND([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx",[Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$9000>=$A$1,[Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$9000<=$A$2), ROW([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000)-ROW(INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000,1,1))+1),1))

Comment: @JeremyPatrick. You are correct. The original formula won't work. See the updated answer.

Comment: I got it to work based on your updated formula.  Thank you!